# Print to R console from within function

Tags: r, console, cat, error-checking

I want to modify the behavior of console printing within an R function, to get back the same behavior as in the global environment.

Much as you can call `browser()` to enter the function environment and access the local variables, I just want to get expressions to print to console.

The goal is to have a flexible and quick way to evaluate many (dozens) of expressions for code checking and understanding statistical properties of intermediate output. I want to do this on the fly, without having to step into the function with a debugger, since this requires additional manual control, and also without having to write out redundant statements like `print("x^2"); print(x^2)`, which I might do, but later in the code development process for more permanent code checks.

What I have in mind is this: write a function `log.to.console()` so that the following is output:

```
myfunlog = function(x){
  log.to.console()
  a1 = sqrt(x)
  a2 = exp(x)
  a1;a2;log(x);x^2
  return(a1*a2)
}
ans = myfunlog(2)
[1] a1
[1] 1.414214
[1] a2
[1] 7.389056
[1] log(x)
[1] 0.6931472
[1] x^2
[1] 4
```

I have a solution which is not quite what I was looking for but, thanks to Hadley's advanced R pages for expressions and scoping I came up with this function:

```
print.to.console = function(...){
  dots = pryr::named_dots(...)
  p = parent.frame()
  for( dot in dots){
    print(dot)
    print(eval(dot, envir = p))
  }
}

myfunprint = function(x){
  a1 = sqrt(x)
  a2 = exp(x)
  print.to.console(
    a1, a2, log(x), x^2
  )
  return(a1*a2)
}
ans = myfunprint(2)
# Which gives the output I want:
a1
[1] 1.414214
a2
[1] 7.389056
log(x)
[1] 0.6931472
x^2
[1] 4
```

Update: I can now call this with explicit scoping with only one function call, whereas before I had to use `environment(print.to.console) = environment()` within `myfunprint()`. However, I would still rather figure out how to implement the `log.to.console()` functionality described above. Any ideas?

Comment: The `print` function does this. I'm not understanding what problems exist. Can you make a small example where `print` fails to produce output to the console?

Comment: I want the expression to print along with the output as shown in the post. This is because in the actual use case we are talking about dozens of long expressions, which I don't want to name individually. I just want to refer to them by their expression calls. I also don't like writing print twice, e.g. print("x^2"); print(x^2), so that every time I modify an expression I also have to modify the string.  If I missed this functionality in `print` please explain. Still I would rather call a `log.to.console()` function that I can call once, much as I would invoke the browser() function. Thanks

Comment: If you define your expressions as objects in your function, you could do something like `all_vars = ls(); for (i in ls) {print(i); print(get(i))}`. Is something like that good?

Comment: I'm confused about what you want `log.to.console` to be, how it is different from `myfunlog` (is that just an example function?) How much of this do you want to be dynamic? Is it really that crucial to be printing expressions, not just objects? Why not just have a `debug` argument passed to your function with default `debug = FALSE`, and have some if statements for printing extra stuff, `if(debug) {print.expressions.to.console()}`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm suggesting constructing a named list with character labels and values

```
prtplus <- function(...){ dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
    anames <-  sapply(dots, deparse); setNames( list(...), anames) }
```

From the `globalenv()` where I had some miscellaneous constants hanging around.

```
print( prtplus( p.lh, p.ml, p.hm) )
$p.lh
[1] 0.1

$p.ml
[1] 0.3

$p.hm
[1] 0.5
```

That `print` was superfluous from the `globalenv()` but would be needed from within a function:

```
myfunlog = function(x){

   a1 = sqrt(x)
   a2 = exp(x)
   print( prtplus(
     a1, a2, log(x), x^2
   ))
   return(a1*a2)
 }

 ans = myfunlog(2)
$a1
[1] 1.414214

$a2
[1] 7.389056

$`log(x)`
[1] 0.6931472

$`x^2`
[1] 4
```

You could also build the `print` into `prtplus`:

```
prtplus <- function(...){ dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
   anames <-  sapply(dots, deparse); print(setNames( list(...), anames)) }
```

If you don't like the print representation of R list with back-ticked names, then this gives exactly the requested "look":

```
prtplus <- function(...){ dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
   anames <-  sapply(dots, deparse)
   vals <- setNames( list(...), anames)
   for(i in seq_along(vals)){ 
        cat( c( names(vals)[i], "\n", round( vals[[i]],6),"\n") ) }
                         }

 ans = myfunlog(2)
#----output to console---
a1 
 1.414214 
a2 
 7.389056 
log(x) 
 0.693147 
x^2 
 4
```

Comment: This is cool, and the `dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]` is good to know about. But it's not quite the full answer I'm looking for...

Comment: Added a looped display with `cat`.

Comment: Cool, we both have a solution that wraps expressions and prints nicely. I was more talking about the first (main) question: is there a way to get expressions to output by just adding a call to some `log.to.console()` function within the body of the function of interest. I know this is a harder problem... but not impossible?

Comment: I think you might need to modify the behavior of `parse` or `eval` so that every expression got echoed to the console. (That's way above my pay grade.) You might want to look at how the `trace` function is operationalized.

Comment: On second thought what would really be needed would be a local redefinition of `<-` (which is merely a function with two arguments). I tried reassigning a function to `<-` and much to my surprise the interpreter didn't complain. (But then R failed to do anything useful, so obviously I now get to keep all the pieces.)

Answer (score 0):

To force the print command to print to console, just use:
print(con=stdout(), "my text")

Beware:
If you previously specified the connection "con" in a previous statement, like readLines(con="inputfile"), then that sets the output connection also for the next print statement, and you will wind up overwriting your inputfile if you do not invoke con=stdout() in your print statement.  It seems that any specification of the connection "con" is saved by R for any next input/output statement.